# How to change text color of Flutter license?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter.  How do I change the text color of the Flutter license? Or if this is not possible, how do I override scaffoldBackgroundColor for a single screen?

I set my scaffoldBackgroundColor in my theme: ThemeData on the main.dart file to black.

But now my Flutter License can't be read because the text has defaulted to black.

I'm wondering if I can customize the text color in my flutter license or override my scaffoldBackgroundColor. I need a white scaffoldBackgroundColor in order for the Flutter license to display properly.

The only issue is if I change the scaffoldBackgroundColor in my main.dart page, it of course changes it for all my other screens which is not what i want. Many thanks for your help!

here is what my theme data looks like in main.dar

```
theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0XFFeb1555),
        accentColor: Color(0XFF5173A8),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xff1D1E33),
        canvasColor: Colors.black,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited three specific parts of the theme data in my main.dart file.
They were heading 5, bodyText2, and caption.

```
 theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0XFFeb1555),
        accentColor: Color(0XFF5173A8),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xff1D1E33),
        canvasColor: Colors.black,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline5: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          caption: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that editing **headlineSmall**, **bodySmall**, **bodyMedium** and **titleMedium** gets the job done:

```
                    textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                      headlineSmall: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      bodySmall: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      bodyMedium: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,),
                      titleMedium: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,),
                    )
                  ),
```

The background and AppBar color can be additionally changed with **cardColor** and **primarySwatch**.